# Scala - Convert a Map with multiple keys into a flat List

Tags: scala

I have a Map in Scala with two keys:-

```
scala> Map(("Alf", "111-111-111") -> 1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, String),Int] = Map((Alf,111-111-111) -> 1)
```

I want to flatten this to create a List as below:-

```
List(Alf, 111-111-111, 1)
```

This seems a simple task, so I apologise in advance if the answer is obvious.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. This is the example my training manual is missing.

Comment: What should the output list look like if you have multiple elements in the Map? Are you OK with external libraries? At a glance this looks like a job for Shapeless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Map(("Alf", "111-111-111") -> 1).flatMap { case ((fst, snd), value) => List(fst, snd, value) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map(("Alf", "111-111-111") -> 1).toList.flatMap(tup => tup._1.productIterator.toList :+ tup._2)
```

This would result in

```
List[Any] = List(Alf, 111-111-111, 1)
```

I am not sure that that is what you actually want since you say you have a map with two keys and you don't. You have a map with one key which is a tuple of arity 2

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work:

```
Map(("Alf", "111-111-111") -> 1).flatMap(x => List(x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))
```